# How to refresh translations in react with phrase app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, phrase

I'm using i18next library in my react app to make some translations. I have json files for each language, which I load on the index.tsx :

```js
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources,
    lng: 'fr',
    fallbackLng: 'fr',
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, I now have to change this system, because I now receive these translations with an axios call to the back end side which is calling phrase app.

The rules I have to follow is a button calling the back end to receive translations and replace them in the project.

I tried to use react only phrase library but a modal is opening to log and this is not wanted.

How can I manage that ?

I'm using react and translations are stored in Phrase app, so maybe the back end is not necessary !

Thanks

Comment: `react only phrase library` do you mean https://react.i18next.com/?

Comment: Hey, I 'm using i18next right now but I tried i18next-phrase-in-context-editor-post-processor to connect to phrase !